# Call parent componentWillUnmount after child componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i have two components "A" and "B".
And "A" renders "B". the `componentWillUnmount` of "A" will called before `componentWillUnmount` of "B".

Is it a good way to put `settimeout` of 0 ms in `componentWillUnmount` of component "A", If i want to do something in `componentWillUnmount` of component "A" **after**  `componentWillUnmount` of "B" was called?

Comment: I would have thought this would be pretty much simultaneous. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You want unmount of B be called before unmount of A? Sounds like you maybe shouldn't use unmount of both A and B but do the stuff in parent of A that causes A to unmount.

Comment: When B and C is unmounted I save the pagination values in mobx store.
And when A is unmounted I want to clear the store.

Comment: But A is reset the store as I want, but after that B and C send their values to the store

Comment: What I meant was that a React component doesn't umnount itself. Do it must have a parent that won't render it anymore because of some state. So why not let that parent handle the paging?

Comment: Or if A unmounts block unmount messages from B and C by setting some state on A unmount.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a function of component "A" to component "B", which is executed in `componentWillUnmount` of component "B" at the very end of the function. It will execute code on component "A" right after unmounting "B".

Comment: Yes. but I have a lot of children to this component

Comment: I don't understand why that is a problem

Comment: And also maybe the child component is unmounted, but the parent isn't unmounted !!!

Comment: That also is no problem. Just create a function on the parent component, pass it to the child(s), and they call it in their `componentWillUnmount` function. It will trigger every time the child is unmounted, regardless of the parent state.